# I can't get PyDev - PYTHONPATH to recognize my Java src directory in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython

In the Project Properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > Source Folders tab I have my Java source directory listed. However, when I try to run my Python file using right-click > Run As > Jython Run, I get "ImportError: cannot import name Person". This is a very simple Python script:

```
from com.entities import Person

person = Person()
print person.getFirstName()
```

I've read some people discuss creating a JAR of the Java application, and then referencing the JAR, but it seems pretty clear that I should be able to reference my source directory.

**EDIT**

So I just tested using a JAR reference containing my class and that worked. So why won't a source folder reference work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it depends on how you structure your java code... you have to add as a source folder the folder that has your .class files (as that's the folder that's added to your pythonpath -- so, depending on how you structure your project, that may be your 'bin' folder).

Reference: read the last lines in: http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I discovered something similar, and as you said, it depends on your project setup. What I did instead was stick with my Java project and have my .py files "compile" into my bin, and that seemed to work.